# What is the meaning of “squiggles out” in the poem “What Is Red" by Mary O' Neill?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, poetry

What is the meaning of “squiggles out”  in the poem “What Is Red" by Mary O' Neill?

[Source](http://meaganfullertonlee.weebly.com/mes-56-poetry/what-is-red-mary-oneill)

> Red ***squiggles out***
>
> when you cut your hand.
>
> Red is a brick
>
> and the sound of a band.

From the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://www.google.com.my/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwivp_yM_sqEAxXkZmwGHQ91D5UQFnoECB0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdictionary.cambridge.org%2Fdictionary%2Fenglish%2Fsquiggle&usg=AOvVaw1eAbFAQDffvanRSOwTIbMX&opi=89978449), squiggles means

> 1. a short line that curls and loops in an irregular way.
> 2. (North America)  wriggle; squirm.

But I don’t understand the meaning of “squiggles out” in the poem? And I am also a little bit confused with the word “out”. Why add the word “out” after  “squiggles” ? Is “squiggles out” a phrasal verb?

What did the author of the poem want to describe for that part ? I think that “squiggles out” is a metaphor. Can anyone explain to me?

Comment: Blood (this seems more suited to Literature SE).

Comment: @StuartF Thanks for your suggestions. I think  I will not migrate this question this site but next time I will ask this type of questions at Literature SE instead of this site.

Comment: I would say no, in this case I wouldn't lump "squiggles out" together as a phrasal; "out" is just a preposition here. You could replace "squiggles" with other verbs and keep "out" and the structure would be the same: drips out, flows out, etc. (Compared to: "runs out" could have a phrasal meaning "be used up" which would change the meaning here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also think it is a metaphor. In case you didn't know these are squiggles
[image: squiggles]
so your blood doesn't run out straight from a cut it "squiggles" around finding the best route.

Comment: I'm not sure it qualifies as a *true* metaphor, just an unusual word choice. "Squiggle" is more often used as a noun than a verb, but the OP's dictionary entry shows that a verb form is possible. It's a word choice that summons a mental image, and the most common context for the word is writing or drawing, but I don't know that we can say the the poem is explicitly *likening* a wound to a drawn design.

Comment: Though reading the rest of the poem, this is almost the only line that *isn't* a metaphor!

Comment: @AndyBonner Oh, it is not a metaphor.

Comment: Using it as a verb is great in this poem. The whole point is to find a different way to say something rather the blood did not spurt out or ooze out. Those would be clichés. It came out in irregular lines. squiggle out: came out in a lessened, irregular manner. +1.